# Using asynchronous output in render loop

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to render the output of an **async** process into the three.js renderer/scene. I came up with 2 ways, both have 2 'loops' though the second one seems more *parallel* than the other:

- **Works, you can try it [here](https://call.orth.uk/video-room):** The render is ran, which triggers the async process but immediately renders what it has (empty scene), and schedules itself to be run again `requestAnimationFrame(render)`, which doesn't happen immediately. When the async process completes, the results are added to the three.js scene, but is not rendered immediately. The render loop will render it when its ready, which repeats.

  - Motivation for not wanting to do this: I initially had a possible memory leak issue probably because I was not disposing the resources (geometry, material), and to dispose resources in this style seemed complicated, I came up with the *next option*:
- A loop which does async processing on the video feed and saves it to a variable (in my case, i use a face mesh library (written at the bottom of the question). A threeJS render loop then takes the saved variable (output of async processing), and puts it in a Buffer and renders it. The first method added it to the three.js immediately, whereas this waits.

  - The issue with my code here is that the 2 loops clump together: loads of render loop run in a row, then loads of async processes run in a row. I discovered this in the debugger/ breakpoints.

[image: Diagram of loops, first diagram is figure of 8, second is two separate circles]

---

### Example of Async process:

NPM: [@mediapipe/face-mesh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mediapipe/face_mesh) API

```js
       const faceMeshModel = new FaceMesh({locateFile: (file) => {
                return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/face_mesh/${file}`;
            }});
        // Write the results handler
        this.model.onResults((results) => {
               /* Preprocess the results into a shape that works with three.js */
               // I've got 2 options here: either call the render loop code directly (works) or
               // Save this result into a class field/ variable, and access this in the render loop.
               // Run the async process here once previous results are generated, so its a loop
               faceMeshModel.send({image: htmlVideoElement})
        })

        // Actually run the process:
        faceMeshModel.send({image: htmlVideoElement})
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to run a render _loop_? Is there a way you can separate the processes such that only input causes a render? This won't be possible if you're running an animation in your scene, but you could maybe also send your async render calls into [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), which will queue them up within the animation loop.

Comment: Even though I took 1 hour to write the question, I don't think I wrote it very well. I think what you're saying is what I did in my first method. I don't actually run the render loop recursively (calling itself when its complete). What I do is: Render, async process, render, async process.

Comment: You're probably going to have to include more details. If you have a working system, then what is the actual problem you're trying to solve? If there is an actual memory leak, where is it occurring? Honestly, your second system seems more complicated than the first, not to mention more prone to de-sync, which is what you're most likely seeing with your log-jam calls.